# ErrorMisc "Unsucessful HTTP code: 400" on cabal update

Tags: cabal, haskell-platform

Having installed Haskell Platform 2013.2.0.0, and using Win7 cmd:

When running the command "cabal update"
I got the following output:

```
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal: Failed to download http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/00-index.tar.gz
: ErrorMisc "Unsucessful HTTP code: 400"
```

To confirm that the link was working, I visited it on my web browser.

At this stage, I'm sorta stuck as to how to resolve the issue.

Also, I'm not sure whether this would help or not, but here's what I get when I run "cabal update -v3"

```
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Sending:
GET /packages/archive/00-index.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
Host: hackage.haskell.org
User-Agent: cabal-install/1.16.0.2
Creating new connection to hackage.haskell.org
Received:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.6.0
Date: Thu, 31 Jul 2014 16:24:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 172
Connection: close
cabal: Failed to download
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/00-index.tar.gz : ErrorMisc
"Unsucessful HTTP code: 400"
```

Comment: Ok, figured out how to deal with it at least. Looks like I simply had to keep trying the command "cabal update -v3" until it got through. The error shows up about 4 out of 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve this problem in my machine by **disabling the antivirus and firewall**, hope it will help.